# Why my Widget saved state when i'm swipe cards?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Scrolling through the cards requires the additional information to be closed again. how do I accomplish this?

I tried using a setter and tried adding a callback, it didn't help, maybe I was doing something wrong?

I am using flutter_card_swiper to scroll through user cards Tinder style.  I generate a list of users using candidates = List.generate and a list of cards using cards = candidates.map(ExampleCard.new).toList() and then pass them to CardSwiper. ExampleCard itself has an AnimatedContainer that expands or contracts depending on the value of _isExpanded. If I expand the container and switch the card, the container will jump, that is, contract first and then expand, and I need the container to stay contract and not expand until the user explicitly expands it.

This is full code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:brew_mate/core/models/person.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_card_swiper/flutter_card_swiper.dart';

class SwipeCardsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwipeCardsWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwipeCardsWidget> createState() => _SwipeCardsWidgetState();
}

class _SwipeCardsWidgetState extends State<SwipeCardsWidget> {
  final CardSwiperController controller = CardSwiperController();

  final cards = candidates.map(ExampleCard.new).toList();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool _onSwipe(
    int previousIndex,
    int? currentIndex,
    CardSwiperDirection direction,
  ) {
    debugPrint(
      'The card $previousIndex was swiped to the ${direction.name}. Now the card $currentIndex is on top',
    );
    return true;
  }

  bool _onUndo(
    int? previousIndex,
    int currentIndex,
    CardSwiperDirection direction,
  ) {
    debugPrint(
      'The card $currentIndex was undod from the ${direction.name}',
    );
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: CardSwiper(
                allowedSwipeDirection: const AllowedSwipeDirection.only(left: true, right: true
                ),
                controller: controller,
                cardsCount: cards.length,
                onSwipe: _onSwipe,
                onUndo: _onUndo,
                numberOfCardsDisplayed: 3,
                backCardOffset: const Offset(40, 40),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                cardBuilder: (
                  context,
                  index,
                  horizontalThresholdPercentage,
                  verticalThresholdPercentage,
                ) =>
                    cards[index],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: controller.undo,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.rotate_left),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () => controller.swipe(CardSwiperDirection.left),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () =>
                        controller.swipe(CardSwiperDirection.right),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () => controller.swipe(CardSwiperDirection.top),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () =>
                        controller.swipe(CardSwiperDirection.bottom),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    final start = Offset(0, size.height / 2);
    final end = Offset(size.width, size.height / 2);
    canvas.drawLine(start, end, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class ExampleCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Person candidate;

  const ExampleCard(
    this.candidate, {
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ExampleCard> createState() => _ExampleCardState();
}

class _ExampleCardState extends State<ExampleCard> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.delta.dy < 0) {
          setState(() {
            _isExpanded = true;
          });
        }
        if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
          setState(() {
            _isExpanded = false;
          });
        }
      },
      child:  Container(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              spreadRadius: 3,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: const Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(widget.candidate.imageUrl), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [Color(0xFFD7E9F7), Color(0xFFD7E9F7)],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              height: _isExpanded ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
              child:  Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: MyLinePainter(),
                          size: const Size(40, 3),
                        ),
                      ),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.candidate.name}, ${widget.candidate.age}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(
                      'Preferred drink: ${widget.candidate.preferredDrink.name}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(
                      'City: ${widget.candidate.location}',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    if (_isExpanded)
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'About me: ${widget.candidate.aboutMe}',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleCandidateModel {
  final String name;
  final String job;
  final String city;
  final List<Color> color;

  ExampleCandidateModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.job,
    required this.city,
    required this.color,
  });
}

const List<DrinkingFrequency> drinkingFrequencies = DrinkingFrequency.values;
const List<PreferredDrink> preferredDrinks = PreferredDrink.values;

final List<Person> candidates = List.generate(
  10,
  (index) => Person(
    id: index + 1,
    name: 'Person ${index + 1}',
    age: Random().nextInt(40) + 18,
    location: 'Location ${index + 1}',
    drinkingFrequency:
        drinkingFrequencies[Random().nextInt(drinkingFrequencies.length)],
    preferredDrink: preferredDrinks[Random().nextInt(preferredDrinks.length)],
    aboutMe: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    imageUrl: 'https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/',
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.
What is the problem? And do you want to achieve?

Also, please provide the code where you are using this card.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему добавив уникальные ключи

```
final cards = candidates.map((candidate) => ExampleCard(candidate, key: ValueKey(candidate.id))).toList();
```